# Remove empty object from an array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap validator to cloning the input and radio elements.
It is working fine, but i have issue while receiving these values as JavaScript array. Because i always have hidden input and radio elements in the DOM so it send empty object.

How i map my array object to receive values

```
var kids = $(".form--group").map(function() {
  return {
     kidName: $(this).find('.thevoornaam').val(),
     newDob: $(this).find('.date_of_birth').val(),
    }
    }).get();
console.log(kids)
```

**I'm receiving values like this..**

```
[{kidName: "Test", newDob:"20"},{kidName: "", newDob:""} ]
```

Always receive second object with empty string.

How can remove the object from array if values are empty or undefined is..

I hope you guys understand my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try and use filter()

Comment: I tried then got error in filter is not define.

Comment: sounds like you used filter wrong, how did you use it?

Comment: Isn't that *child cruelty* packing "kids" into arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` to filter out the empty object like this

```
var kids = $(".form--group").map(function() {
  return {
     kidName: $(this).find('.thevoornaam').val(),
     newDob: $(this).find('.date_of_birth').val(),
  }
}).get();

kids = kids.filter(function (kid) {
  return kid.kidName && kid.newDob;
});

console.log(kids)
```

Comment: Is this considered better practice than not inserting empty values into the array in the first place? It seems like its more time intensive (two loops) but simpler than my example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude the item when every property is empty, undefined or 0;

```js
let obj = [{kidName: "Test", newDob:"20"},{kidName: "", newDob:""} ];



let filtered = obj.filter(e=>{
    for(let p in e){
        if(e[p]){
            return true;
        }
    }
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the strings before you create the objects:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var kids = $(".form--group").map(function() {
      
      var kidName = $(this).find('.thevoornaam').val();
      var dob = $(this).find('.date_of_birth').val();
      var result_arr = [];

      if(kidName || dob)
      {
         var obj = {kidName: kidName, newDob: dob}
         result_arr.push(obj);
      }
      
      return result_arr;
  
    }).get();
console.log(kids)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form--group">
    <input class="thevoornaam" value="Test Name" />
    <input class="date_of_birth" value="Test Date" />
</div>

<div class="form--group">
    <input class="thevoornaam" value="" />
    <input class="date_of_birth" value="" />
</div>

<div class="form--group">
    <input class="thevoornaam" value="Test Name" />
    <input class="date_of_birth" value="Test Date" />
</div>
```